# SCSS doesn't load on Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby, server-side-rendering, gatsby-plugin

i try to load the SASS for my Gatsby Project but if I check the source code of the web there isn't any classes from my sass.
I am a bit confused and I followed the documentation of Gatsby.
Nothing worked so my last chance is SO.

```
// gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
'gatsby-plugin-fontawesome-css',
'gatsby-plugin-sass',
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
  options: {
    name: 'assets',
    path: `${__dirname}/static/`,
  },
 },
]
```

Here I import the style.

```
/**
 * Add browser relation logic.
 */
require('./style/global.js');
import './style/sass/index.scss';
```

I followed the gatsby-plugin-sass documentation and I should be all set. After restarting the server and show source-code of my app there is now class name from my sass file.

Best Regards
Knome

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a `className` that is not appearing?

Comment: @FerranBuireu For example .grid-container

Comment: Can you provide the component please? (edit the question)

Comment: @FerranBuireu I didn't integrate in any component. Because if I see the Source code of chrome then there should be scss be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't integrate in any component. Because if I see the Source code
> of chrome then there should be scss be loaded.

Ok, well... The SCSS is loaded as it should but the styles are not applied to **any** component because you've not set any class name.

Just do:

```
const IndexPage =()=>{

   return <div className="grid-container">I'm your index page</div>
}
```

Like any other HTML element.